# Hide result div when search field is empty - Ajax Live Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to make a simple Ajax Live Search for my project and Javascript isn't my strong side. When the search phrase is greater than 0 it should make an AJAX request, set the html and show the result-div (by SlideDown). If the phrase length then go back to zero the result-div should slide up.

The problem for me is that when the length go back to zero, the AJAX call made by the phrase with length 1 isn't done yet (because it a asynchronous request) and then showing the result div again with the result from that last request, even when the input field is empty.

Ex. I search for "Horse" and all works fine. Then when I'm deleting characters so the input is empty, the div slides up and then slides down again with the result of search "H".

How do i solve this?

Code

```
let delayTimer;
$('.search').on('keyup', function () {
    let phrase = $(this).val();

    if (phrase.length > 0) {

        clearTimeout(delayTimer);

        delayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '.......',
                    data: {
                        phrase: phrase
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        let el = $('#search-result');

                        if (response.type == 'success') {
                            el.html(response.html)
                        } else if (response.type == 'error') {
                            el.html(response.message)
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        let el = $('#search-result');

                        if (el.is(':hidden')) {
                            el.slideDown(300)
                        }
                    }
                });
        }, 350);
    } else {
        let el = $('#search-result');

        if  (el.is(":visible")) {
            el.stop().slideUp(300);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite simple. You can abort an `ajax()` request simply by using `.abort()`. So assign your `ajax()` call to a variable, for example "my_ajax_request". When there are 0 characters in the search field, just call `my_ajax_request.abort();`

Comment: Hi, thx for the answer.
It didn't work for me. The readyState for the request was 4 when the phrase length equals zero.. Maybe i did it wrong.
But you gave me an idea that solved my problem. I made a variable setHtml = true outside the keyup function and if phrase.length == 0: setHTML = false. Then when the previous request made it to the complete function i could check the setHTML. It worked.